# Is there a way to make a nested loop use the same counter as the loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If there is not, how can I make this code with fewer lines considering I might have many divs?

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".content");
var photoes = document.querySelectorAll(".images");
var para = document.querySelectorAll("p");

divs[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
    photoes[0].classList.toggle("showImage");
    para[0].classList.toggle("showText");
});
divs[1].addEventListener("click", function(){
    photoes[1].classList.toggle("showImage");
    para[1].classList.toggle("showText");
});
divs[2].addEventListener("click", function(){
    photoes[2].classList.toggle("showImage");
    para[2].classList.toggle("showText");
});
```

Comment: Yes, you can use a loop instead of manually listing the indicies - have you tried implementing a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `spread` operator and `map` function with param `(item, index)` as

```
var photoes = document.querySelectorAll(".images");
var para = document.querySelectorAll("p");

[...document.querySelectorAll(".content")].map((item, index)=>{
  item.addEventListener("click", function(){
    photoes[index].classList.toggle("showImage");
    para[index].classList.toggle("showText");
});
}
```

```js
var photoes = document.querySelectorAll(".images");
var para = document.querySelectorAll("p");

[...document.querySelectorAll(".content")].map((item, index)=>{
  item.addEventListener("click", function(){
    photoes[index].classList.toggle("showImage");
    para[index].classList.toggle("showText");
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".content");
var photoes = document.querySelectorAll(".images");
var para = document.querySelectorAll("p");

divs.forEach(function (div, index) {
    div.addEventListener("click", function(){
       photoes[index].classList.toggle("showImage");
       para[index].classList.toggle("showText");
    }
})
```

Check [Array.prototype.forEach documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for further information on the method and its params.